# Did classical physicists believe there was an infinite amount of matter in the universe?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, cosmology, history

Forgive my naive usage of the term 'classical physicists' but what I mean is physicists who were either unaware of probabilistic quantum mechanics or refused it entirely. I am interested in whether they thought there was an infinite amount of matter in the universe, and whether space was infinite.

Comment: Might [hsm.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: One of the posts on [Olber's paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=olber%2A+paradox) might be helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to another SE site, https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also would fit on [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/), which accepts history questions.

Answer (score 1):

Before we got good telescopes, it appeared to astronomers that the Milky Way was the entire universe- which would have made its matter content finite.

Better telescopes and the use of photographic film instead of the astronomer's eye demonstrated that other galaxies existed farther away from us, and the debate about the matter content of the resulting universe began.